# Windows 8 wallpaper slideshow simply does not work - Fresh Install

Tags: windows-8, desktop-customization, slideshow

this has been driving me crazy for the past few days, I have a fresh and clean install of Windows 8 Pro 64Bit (Activated - Not upgrade).

I have about 50 JPEG wallpapers that I want to set as a slideshow - 10 mintes each on shuffle. my monitor is a big 27" hi res (2560x1440 resolution) so keep in mind that some images are big in size, my largest image is about 2MB, the whole collection is 46MB

The problem is, when I set all my images as slideshow and save, windows will maybe play only about 2 images, then it gets stuck on the third and never change at all, not even after a restart! Sometimes it would work but flip through images at a faster rate, about 1 minute each image for like 2-3 images then gets stuck again! - every-time it gets stuck at a random image, not the same image.

I dont have any problems setting one image only as a wallpaper, I only have problems with the slideshow!

Things I have tried:

- make sure slideshow in power settings is set to available and not paused
- deleted transcodedwallpaper and slideshow.ini files, they regenerate back automatically
- I even re-installed windows thinking maybe my install is corrupted, same behavior
- I do not RDP or use VNC

Programs I have installed (which by no means should interfere with the wallpaper process):

- Nvidia Control Panel
- Adobe Creative Cloud
- Skydrive
- Steam (with some games)

That is literally all I have installed! I really hope somebody can help me out

---

Edit: Forgot to mention, this is a Desktop not a Laptop, It stays on the whole time. No screensaver.

Comment: Do fewer images or a completely different set of images work better? Perhaps there's something about the image encoding it doesn't like.

Comment: Fewer images do work better, if I choose any 5-10 images, it works ok, but anything more than that and it will start acting up!

Comment: The number of images is not a problem. I had set a wallpaper slideshow  consisting of more than 300 images in my Windows 8 desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

Open explorer and type the following in the address bar and hit Enter:

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\

Here, rename TranscodedWallpaper.jpg to TranscodedWallpaper.old.

Next, double-click slideshow.ini file and open it with Notepad. Empty its contents. That is, select all the text and delete it. Save the changes. Close explorer windows.

source:
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/cannot-change-desktop-background-windows